# Reliability of system with two parallel, exponential components

Tags: probability

A system consists of two components connected in parallel whose lifetimes are independent and distributed according to an Exp($λ$) distribution. A second system consists of a single component whose lifetime is distributed according to an Exp($μ$) distribution. Calculate the probability that the first system fails before the second.

I'm stuck at finding the distribution for the lifetime of the first system.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Juan, what do you mean? Are you saying that the system will break with the exponential probability after a time $t$, don't you?

Comment: I think that you can say that $P\{\text{Syst_1 - break}\} = 1-e^{-\lambda t}$

Comment: @PierrePolovodov: Your comment would be true if there was just one component, here two are in parallel.

Comment: @trueblueanil, are this components independent of each other? I mean if they are, the probability of each one should be independent, shouldn't it?

Comment: @PierrePolovodov: In a parallel system, if only one fails, the system doesn't fail,

Comment: Ah, ok, I see now. In the first case each element of the parallel system has $\lambda$-distribution, is that so?

Comment: @PierrePolovodov: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

The reliability of  part of the system with two components connected in parallel will be

$R_A = 1 - \left(1-e^{-\lambda t}\right)^2$

That of the other part will be

$R_B = e^{-\mu t}$

You should be able to proceed from here

**PS**

You can look up [this](https://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue181/article181.htm) if you need more details

Comment: it is weird, in the first formula the reliability reaches 0 when $t \rightarrow \infty$ and in the bottom formula - 1. I would expected that the both limits are the same. I mean both systems should break eventually and a probability of that should be the same 1 in the end.

Comment: Souldn't there be no 1 and no "-" on the left of exponential in the bottom system? I mean when time passes, the system become less reliable so, the reliability should reach 0 after a big enough time.

Comment: @PierrePolovodov: The exponential model implies that the age of the product has no effect on the probability of failure ! Of course it is a simplification which may look unrealistic, but it is widely used as a simple model, and this particular question uses the exponential distribution.

Comment: @PierrePolovodov: Furthermore, when components are connected in parallel, the resulting reliability function doesn't remain the simple exponential distribution ! So it is weird, but that's the model ! More than that, I can't say anything !

Comment: PierrePolovodov is quite correct when he says that the probability that system B survives (has not failed) till time $t$ should be $e^{-\mu t}$ (and thus decaying away to $0$ as $t \to \infty$) and not $1-e^{-\mu t} \to 1$ as true blue anil is mis-typing.

Comment: @trueblueanil, I just want to say as Dilip Sarwate said, that there seems to be a typos for the B system.

Comment: And following your reference it should be so

Comment: And assuming that reliability should decrease and reach 0 when time passes, if I understand correctly

Comment: The problem statement seems ambiguous to me, since it doesn't clearly define what failure of the first system means.  This answer assumes that it doesn't fail until *both* of its components have failed. [Sri-Amirthan Theivendran's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4660279/reliability-of-system-with-two-parallel-exponential-components/4660521#4660521), on the other hand, assumes that it fails as soon as *either* of its two components has failed.

Comment: As true blue anil mentions in a comment, the fact that the components are specified as being in "parallel"  does *suggest* that the first assumption is the correct one, but I wouldn't regard that as being conclusive

Comment: the first system fails when both of its components fail. If only one of its components fail, the system will continue working

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Sorry for the horrendous typo for $B$ which changed the complexion. For the parallel system, it is OK (with the exponential distribution as base) More sophisticated models are there, eg Weibull Distribution, but all that is outsife the scope of the current question.

Comment: @PierrePolovodov: I have corrected the typo for system B

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the failure times of the two components of the first system and $Y$ be the failure time of the second system. The first system has failure time $Z=\min(X_1, X_2)$ where $Z\sim \text{Exp}(2\lambda)$ since $P(Z\gt z) = P(X_{1}>z)^2=e^{-2\lambda}$. So we seek the probability $P(Z<Y)=1-P(Z\geq Y)$. But note that
$$
P(Z\geq Y)=\int_{0}^\infty P(Z\geq y\mid Y=y)f_{Y}(y)\, dy=\int_{0}^\infty P(Z\geq y)f_{Y}(y)\, dy
$$
where we use the law of total probability and assume that $Z$ is independent of $Y$. Here $f_{Y}$ is the density of $Y$. You can compute the integral.

Comment: why is Z=min(X1,X2)?? i think Z = max(X1,X2), because in a parallel system , it fails if both of its components fails